# Limiting table rows in Oracle BI Publisher

Tags: oracle, rtf, xsl-fo, bi-publisher

I'm making an RTF template using Oracle BIP, how do I limit my table to 10 rows? Currently sorting the data by column3 in descending order.
Here's the current code:
`<?for-each:DataRow?><?sort:column3;'descending';data-type='number'?>`

Tried using the position property, but can't make it work.

Comment: What is the **source**? Some query? If so, limit number of rows there.

Comment: @Littlefoot someone else is sending me XML data, I don't have control over the queries used to get that data.

Comment: I see; can you ask them to do that for you? If not, then - no, sorry, I wouldn't know how to do that in BIP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could use a predicate like this:

```
<?for-each:DataRow[position()&lt;=10]?>
```